# How to avoid #include in header files when forward declaration causes incomplete type error?

Tags: c++, header-files, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

How to avoid #include in header files when forward declaration causes incomplete type error?

This is my `ray.h` header file. When I implement forward declaration `Vector` turns an incomplete type. In this case, I Will have to use #include in a header file?

```cpp
#include "vector.h"

struct Ray {
    Vector position, direction; // error: incomplete type when it uses forward declaration

    Ray();
    Ray(Vector position, Vector direction);
    ~Ray();
};
```

Comment: Why are you asking how to avoid it, when *not* avoiding it is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way `Ray` struct is defined, every `.cpp` file that uses `Ray` will also have to know `Vector`, so if you only have a forward declaration in `ray.h`, it will have to `#include "vector.h"` before any `#include "ray.h"`. This is inconvenient.

Therefore, it is easiest for everyone if you just add the `#include "vector.h"` to `ray.h`. Then, people can `#include "ray.h"` and start using `Ray` without requiring an extra `#include`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to avoid `#include`. You can use `Vector*` (pointer to `Vector`) or `std::unique_ptr<Vector>` (which is virtually the same, but no need to explicitly allocate\deallocate the fields).

Comment: However, doing this adds overhead, since the resulting objects will have to be allocated separately on the heap instead of simply being part of the `Ray` object.